# Some misunderstanding about macro expansion

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I have the following code which doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\tracingcommands=2
\tracingmacros=2
\tracingall

\makeatletter

\let\sep\relax

\def\put@stack@#1#2{\edef#2{#1\sep#2}}

\def\put@queue@#1#2{\edef#2{#2\sep#1}}

\def\get@#1#2{\expandafter\get@@#2\endget@@#1#2}

\def\get@@#1\sep#2\endget@@#3#4{\edef#3{#1}\edef#4{#2}}

\def\empty@stack{\sep}

\newtoks\piecetoks

\def\leftrightbr{
    \let\o@left\left
    \let\o@right\right
    \let\piece@nd\relax
    \let\pieces@stack\empty@stack
    \let\delims@stack\empty@stack
    \let\on@end@line\empty@stack
    \let\on@begin@line\empty@stack
    \def\left##1{
        \piece@nd
        \let\piece@nd\endgroup
        \def\on@first@right{
            \put@stack@{\the\toks0}{\pieces@stack}
        }
        \put@stack@{##1}{\delims@stack}
        \let\repl\relax
        \let\vphantomer####1{}
        \put@stack@{\the\piecetoks}{\pieces@stack}
        \put@stack@{\right.}{\on@end@line}
        \put@stack@{\left.}{\on@begin@line}
        \piecetoks=\begingroup
    }
    \def\right##1{
        \endgroup
        \on@first@right
        \let\on@first@right\relax
        \get@\@dummy\on@end@line
        \get@\@dummy\on@begin@line
        \get@\@lpart\pieces@stack
        \get@\@ldelim\delims@stack
        \ifx\@lpart\empty
            \repl
        \else
            \edef\repl{\o@left\@ldelim\@lpart\vphantomer{\the\piecetoks}\repl\the\piecetoks\vphantomer{\@lpart}\o@right##1}
        \fi
    }
    \def\mathbr{
        \piece@end
        \put@stack@{\piece}{\pieces@stack}
        \let\vphantomer\vphantom
        \edef\repl{\on@end@line \\ \on@begin@line}
        \def\piece\begingroup
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \leftrightbr
    \left(a\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

So what's the catch?

**EDIT:** The error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \@dummy 

l.85     \left(
               a\right)
```

Looking into log gets us to conclusion that the problem is caused by call to `\get@\@dummy\on@end@line`. This seems to be strange since direct call to \get@ on \empty@stack results in no error.

**EDIT:** The code can be narrowed down:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\tracingcommands=2
\tracingmacros=2
\tracingall

\newtoks\piecetoks

\def\leftrightbr{
    \def\left##1{
        \piecetoks=\begingroup
    }
    \def\right##1{
        \endgroup
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \leftrightbr
    \left(a\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

This is shorter, isn't it? :-) It gives the other error, and **the other question** arises: how can we achieve behavior in  which TeX captures tokens between two macros' calls?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get `Undefined control sequence \@some` with the second code. It would be beneficial if you explained what the macros are supposed to do.

Comment: After fixing the typos `\@some` to `\some` both files run without errors.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I have much more code and while trying to make MWE i obviously mistyped.

Comment: Maybe it's not so much code after all. I'll edit the question in a couple of minutes.

Comment: And just updated one questions' code is all about first attempt to make \left and \right work across lines.

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov Without global definitions?

Comment: @egreg Yes, why not?

Comment: I suggest closing the question since narrowing code down to single token register assignment starting in `\left` and stopping in `\right` already gives compile error.

Comment: So what's the catch? You forgot to define `\def\@dummy` plus a lot more things which are missing in the MWE.

Comment: The question now is - how to achieve such a behavior?

Comment: @YiannisLazarides I think you are not quite correct. \@dummy should get defined by `\get@` macro.

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov you have not given any indication of what the code is supposed to do, all we can know is that it generates an error, deleting it all will make the error go away but presumably that is not the desired result?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Code is all about first attempt to make `\left` and `\right` work across line breaks.

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov you said that above but that is hardly enough information. What _in detail_ do you expect that input to produce. you said above you could simplify the MWE to a single assignment, perhaps you should do that. Otherwise this question should be closed with the built in "unclear what you are asking"  reason

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, sorry. Well, right now i need to close the question and i just don't know exactly how to do it properly (for what exact reason and stuff like that).

Comment: I think as the OP you can just delete it, otherwise if you click `close` _unclear_ is offered as a standard close reason. But if you can clarify the question that is better than closing it:-)

Comment: @egreg I actually already (almost) understood that. But how the desired behavior i.e. capturing the tokens between one macro and one of the two others can be accomplished?

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov With a delimited macro argument. Your `\left` expects a `\right`, so you can gather all tokens between them. But, if you plan to use this with `amsmath` alignments, I can see *many* other problems.

Comment: @egreg Thought of that. Actually my `\left` expects either `\right` or some `\mathcr`. So that makes it not possible, right?

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov Much more complicated, at least.

Comment: @egreg What's the way you could imagine then?

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov `breqn` and `nath` do something like you'd want. My opinion is that `\left` and `\right` must be used very sparingly.

Comment: @egreg `breqn` is much less appealing than `nath` in my opinion and `nath`  has a lot of incompatibilities. Maybe `nath` can be "repaired" using `flexisym`? And for clarity - there is no way to have two variants of delimited arguments?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek (and others but I can ping you:-) The question has been clarified more now, it could be re-opened,

Answer (score 7):

You can't assign tokens to a token register with

```
\piecetoks=\begingroup...\endgroup`
```

Nor you can start the assignment with a macro and end it with another one, because

```
<toks register>={...}
```

needs an *explicit* brace at the end and no expansion takes place during the evaluation of the `<balanced text>` to be stored.

In the TeXbook, page 276, you find what a `<variable assignment>` is; one of the alternatives is

```
<token variable> <equals> <general text>
```

and some lines above you see

```
<general text> → <filler> { <balanced text> <right brace>
```

In the syntax rules, `{` means an implicit or explicit character token of category code 1, while `<right brace>` means an *explicit* character token of category code 2.

Answer (score 7):

Delimited arguments need to look for a fixed token, but you don't need to look ahead for `\\`-or-`\right` you can look ahead for `\right` and then look in the tokens you collected to see if there was a `\\`.

so

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\newtoks\tA
\newtoks\tB

\def\left#1\right{%
  \zz#1\\\right}

\def\zz#1\\#2\right#3{%
\ifx\relax#2\relax
  \tA{\left#1\right#3}%
  \typeout{^^J^^Jno \space\string\\:^^J\the\tA^^J}%
  \expandafter\remove@to@nnil
\else
  \tA{\left#1\right.\\}%
  \expandafter\zzb
 \fi
 #2\right#3\@nnil}

\def\zzb#1\\\right#2\@nnil{%
  \tB{\left.#1\right#2}%
  \typeout{^^J^^Jhas \string\\:^^J\the\tA\space \the\tB^^J}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\left( a b\right)

\left( a \\ b\right)

\end{document}
```

produces

```
no  \\:
\left ( a b\right )



has \\:
\left ( a \right .\\ \left . b\right )
```

However I would never use this in production. redefining `\left` and `\right` to take macro arguments changes their scanning rules and will introduce all kinds of incompatibilities. Even if you avoid that by using new names rather than redefining the primitives, using `\right.\\ \left.` at the line break does not ensure that the paired delimiters are the same size so can not produce an acceptable result.

It is better really just to use `\bigl(` in one cell and `\bigr)` in a later cell.

Comment: I thought that `\vphantom` will ensure that corresponding delimiters wil have the same size. Was i wrong?

Comment: Another question - are there rules on how to select sizes for delimiters?

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov not really, just whatever looks best, it's a subjective judgement. In particular depending on the context sometimes you always want different sizes for nested pairs so the outer ones in `((a+b)+(c+d))` are bigger, and sometimes you don't.

Comment: @AndrewZabavnikov I mainly answered your argument scanning question, as indicated in comments on the question it was hard to guess what the original code was doing. If you grab everything and measure then it's possible to use vphantom to ensure equal size stretching, yes.